# Batch: IF and delayed expansion

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, delayedvariableexpansion

I have a batch file for downloading youtube videos as `01-title1.m4a`, `02-title2.m4a` etc. I'm having trouble getting the video number `n` to work properly, though. If it's a single digit number I want to append a zero in front, but I can't get it to work.

If I change the `IF` line in the `FOR` to `IF %n%==%n:~0,1% SET n=0!n!`, it does work, but then only the initial value of `n` is used in the comparison. Yet when I do `echo !n!==!n:~0,1!` just before the `IF`, I get `1==1`, `2==2` as expected.

```
:: Enter YouTube link including https, or just the video ID
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET url_list=
:loop
SET url=
SET /P url="Enter URL: "
SET url="%url%"
IF %url%=="" GOTO endloop
IF %url%=="%url:~1,11%" (SET url=%url:~1,11%) ELSE SET url=%url:~33,11%
SET url_list=%url_list% %url%
GOTO loop
:endloop
SET url_list=%url_list:~1%
SET /P n="Enter n: "
IF [%n%] == [] SET n=1
FOR %%u IN (%url_list%) DO (
    IF !n!==!n:~0,1! SET n=0!n!
    youtube-dl --output "D:\Users\Joakim\Downloads\!n!-%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" --extract-audio --format 18 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%%u"
    SET /A n+=1
)
```

Comment: The problem is you are setting `n` to an octal number by preceding it with a zero.  You can't add 1 to 08 and 09.  Just do a substring instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
....
set /a zn=100+n
youtube-dl --output "D:\Users\Joakim\Downloads\!zn:~-2!-%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" --extract-audio --format 18 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%%u"
....
```

`set /a` uses the *run-time* values of its arguments to set its target variable, so `zn` is set to the *run-time* value of `n` +100. Then use the last 2 characters of `zn` in the `youtube-dl` line.